# How to write a TreeMap for this program?

Tags: java, treemap

I have a file `pacs.txt` with:

```
a,b,c,d
```

Then I have another file `members.txt` with:

```
sara a,c
brad d,a
tammy c,b
```

I have to basically print out

```
a sara, brad
b tammy
c sara tammy
```

I have written a code that tries to do this. I went in and asked for help from my TA and she says I'm really close I'm just messing up my Treemap. Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. List A is pacsFile and List B is membersFile.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// N O   C O M M A N D  L I N E   A R G S!
// A L L   F I L E N A M E S  M U S T  B E  H A R D C O D E D

public class Pacs
{
public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception
{
        BufferedReader pacsFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "pacs.txt" ) );
        BufferedReader membersFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "members.txt" ) );
        TreeMap<String,String> Map = new TreeMap<String,String>();
        ArrayList<String> acroymn = new ArrayList<String>();
        String group;
        String people;
        while((group = pacsFile.readLine()) != null)
        {
            acroymn.add(group);
        }
        Collections.sort(acroymn);
        pacsFile.close();
        while((membersFile.ready()))
        {
            ArrayList<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();
            people = membersFile.readLine();
            String [] peoples = people.split(" ");
            members.add(peoples[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i< peoples.length; i++)
            {

                Map.put(peoples[i],peoples[0]);
            }

        }
        membersFile.close();

        for(String acro: acroymn)
        {
            String name = "";
            for(String mem: Map.keySet())
            {
                for(String S: Map.get())
                {
                    if(acro.equals(S))
                    {
                        name = name+ " " + mem;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(acro + " " + name);      


        }


} // END MAIN

} // CLASS
```

Comment: What are your results?

Comment: @Desertlvy I had just finished reading and was about to comment the exact same text XD

Comment: Irrelevant, but what is so bad about command line arguments? :)

Comment: @squiguy Educational purpose I guess, one problem at a time is probably better to understand how things work ;)

Comment: Please post your current result/error, it will help us help you.

Comment: It says no suitable method for get() for the map.get() I used in the for loop

Comment: @Ayoshna This is because of the way you defined your map. You're defining `ArrayList<String>`s as keys, and `String`s as values. In the loop, you try to access content with a `Set` as key, this is not the right type.

Comment: Okay I've changed that as just string,string tree map but I'm still getting that error. Let me update my code because I've moved a lot around

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how you're storing the data. It would be better to store it like this:

```
TreeMap<String, List<String>> data = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Where the elements in first file (a, b, c, d) will be the keys and the names in second file (sara, brad, tammy) will be the values to be added for each entry of the map.

At the end, just print the key-value pair that don't have any `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

### Current problems

I see several problems in the way you read the information in the files.

#### Reading `"pacs.txt"`

First, I feel like the `acronym` list will only contain a single element with all the letters:

```
while((group = pacsFile.readLine()) != null)
{
    acroymn.add(group);
}
```

If the first line of your file actually contains all letters separated by commas (as you stated), then this will only add a single element to the list: the string `"a,b,c,d"`.

You should probably use `group.split(",")` and then add its elements to your list.

#### Reading `"members.txt"`

Second, it seems that you loop on `people` without accessing different indices:

```
for (int i = 0; i< peoples.length; i++)
{
    members.add(peoples[0]);
    Map.put(acroymn,peoples[0]);
}
```

You always access 0.

### Possible solution

You're currently storing the content of one file in a data structure, the content of the other file in another data structure, and then putting everything together.

You should probably follow @LuiggiMendoza's advice here, and use a `Map<String, List<String>`. Use this structure directly in both steps of the process.

Here are some hints about what you can do with it.

#### Reading `"pacs.txt"`

Add all elements as keys of your map using:

```
map.put(element, new LinkedList<String>());
```

This way, all your keys will be present, even with noone associated with. Moreover this will initialize the lists of people to empty lists that you will just need to complete.

#### Reading `"members.txt"`

For each person, obtain the list corresponding to each key of the line using:

```
List<String> list = map.get(key);
```

And add your person to it:

```
list.add(person);
```